# How to add custom button inside the list in Windchill GUI

Tags: java, list, button, ptc-windchill

I'm using Windchill 10.0 M030. In my GUI I need to add an custom button in reports toolbar drop down list.

Following image shows my question clearly

[image: GUI]

I have tried adding entries in the psb-actionmodels.xml file under  the corresponding model name like this

```
<model name="psbRelatedPartsTreeToolBar">
....
<action name="psbReportsGroupGWT" type="psb" />
      <action name="psbReportsGWT" type="psb" />
      <action name="psbReportMultiLevelCompListGWT" type="psb" />
      <action name="separator" type="separator" />
      <action name="psbReportSingleLevelConsolBOMGWT" type="psb" />
      <action name="psbReportSingleLevelBOMGWT" type="psb" />
      <action name="psbReportSingleLevelBOMWithNotesGWT" type="psb" />
      <action name="separator" type="separator" />
      <action name="psbReportMultiLevelBOMGWT" type="psb" />
      <action name="psbReportMultiLevelBOMWithReplacementsGWT" type="psb" />
      <action name="seperator" type="seperator" />
      <action name="HBOMReportsGWT" type="psb" />
      <action name="psbReportMultiLevelBOMWithAMLAVLGWT" type="psb" />
      <action name="psbReportMultiLevelBOMWithAMLGWT" type="psb" />
      <action name="separator" type="separator" />
      <action name="singleSourceOEMPartsGWT" type="psb" />
      <action name="uniqueManufacturerPartsGWT" type="psb" />
      <action name="separator" type="separator" />
      <action name="changeBaselineReportGWT" type="change" />         
      <action name="exportActionsGWT" type="cat"/>
      <action name="exportCsvGWT" type="cat" />
      <action name="exportHtmlGWT" type="cat" />
      <action name="exportTextGWT" type="cat" />
      <action name="exportXlsGWT" type="cat" />
      <action name="exportXlsxGWT" type="cat" />
      <action name="exportXlsReportGWT" type="cat" />
      <action name="exportXmlGWT" type="cat" />
      <action name="newButton" type="cat" />
   </model>
```

I have added my button called newButton here and I have corresponding entry in cat-actions.xml file.

But the button is not coming in that list.Is this the way Correct one??Or I don't know how to add the button over there.Someone suggest me in which are xml files I need to change and what are class file or rbInfo to be changed??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ribbon Bar customization is currently not supported by PTC.

If you want to integrate new button in this menu, you need a good understanding of GWT (Google Web Toolkit), as this button bar is developped with GXT libraries. I would not recommend this, as you will never get support from PTC on this subject.

The new button you've added to psb-actionmodels.xml should appear by right click on the product structure browser (in your screenshot, on HBOM22 part).

Getting action in the contextual menu is usually a good solution. Then you can customize for which object type, this action is available (in typeBasedActionFilter.properties configuration file)

Comment: I cannot find this `typeBasedActionFilter.properties` inside codebase.Please tell me where do I find this?

Comment: This file is located in codebase directory : $WT_HOME/codebase/typeBasedActionFilter.properties

Comment: I'm using WIndchill 10.0 and I can't find that properties file in codebase location.Please correct me if I'm missing something

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, I've made a mistake. typeBasedActionFilter.properties is included in a specific module (not available in standard PDMLink distribution).
You can use <supportedTypes> <nonSupportedTypes> tags available in all *-actions.xml. (See psb-actions.xml for some examples)

Comment: Yes I got that.Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You must change native class com.ptc.windchill.mpml.ppb.server.PPBTreeConfigBuilder
Buttons are created in the  **getToolbarConfigOverrides** method